# In Scrum 2020: Who decides if and when to release the Product Increment?

Tags: scrum

I am a bit confused if it is the Product Owner or the entire Scrum Team?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Scrum Guide does not describe who decides or when to release an increment, just that the Sprint could result in one or more releasable increments that meet the Definition of Done.

Just like a lot of things, for this the Scrum framework does not set it in stone, it depends on your context. Experiment, inspect and adapt.

Typical I think the Product Owner would coordinate with the stakeholders when to release the product and in what frequency. Preferably as soon as possible as companies with a higher deployment frequency and shorter feature lead time tend to be more successful (according to the book *Accelerate: The Science of Lean Software and DevOps: Building and Scaling High Performing Technology Organizations*)

Answer (score 5):

Normally, it's the PO that decides when to release an increment. After each sprint you could release a product increment, but the PO might want to delay that for some reason. Maybe there is some upcoming business convention in two months or something, and they just want to hang on to the developed features and release them all before the convention just to wow the audience with a new version of the product, etc.

Sometimes, teams do continuous deployment and they release multiple increments per sprint, as things are done. Sometimes they can even release changes a few times per day. Maybe an increment with bug fixes and performance enhancements gets released immediately, while for increments that contain new features the team might hold on to them just so they [don't overwhelm users](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/30852/how-to-handle-business-change-within-an-agile-development-environment) (if users just receive the software to use instead of being involved in building it and expecting changes and knowing what comes their way, for example).

At the end of the day this really depends on the team and how they organize their work, on the company, on the product, and on the increment itself, with the PO's word having the heaviest weight, since [they are the PO after all](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/29734/who-is-the-owner-of-the-increment-in-scrum).

Answer (score 0):

Also: "a *release"* can be a more-complicated business process than simply finishing a new set of source-code.  It will need to be coordinated with the various end-users of the system.  The PO is the most logical representative of the team, but agreement and planning needs to be secured from the user community as well.